# checking for mysql,connector errors in python

Tags: python, mysql

Is it possible to get to mysql.connect errors in a Python code without using try-except construction?

And if it is possible to get by without try - except code, then how to prevent the Traceback messages from being shown up on the log? 
Thanks.
Boris.

Comment: Python uses as one of the design principles EAFP: **E**asier to **A**sk **F**orgiveness than **P**ermission. There is nothing wrong with using `try`-`except`.

Comment: Stack Overflow was built on a good principle that is known as RGQ&GA - Repository of Good Questions & Good Answers.

Comment: well it is technically possible to do it without using `try`: you can make a context manager. But it is a serious anti-pattern. It is like people here asking "how can I assign to `var + i = ...`". The answer is almost always (you can check it), you do *not*: it makes it unreadable, hard to understand and dangerous. If you `import this` on a Python shell, you see what is considered *pythonic*.